# Received Intent data different from sent intent data in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

Kind of stumped on this one.  The intent data that I sent is correct (I used logging to view it), however, when I get the intent, it has completely different values.

Why/how is this happening?

**Sending Intent:**

```
Intent viewUser = new Intent(ActivitiyMap.this, viewUser.class);
            viewUser.putExtra("latitude", String.valueOf(markerLat));
            viewUser.putExtra("longitude", String.valueOf(markerLong));
            viewUser.putExtra("userName", marker.getTitle());
            Log.d("userName", marker.getTitle());
            startActivity(viewUser);
```

**Recieving Intent:**

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
            userName = intent.getStringExtra("userName");
            userLat = intent.getStringExtra("latitude");
            userLong = intent.getStringExtra("longitude");
```

EDIT: Updated to use the right intent "viewUser".  However still not passing the right information.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: show some code please

Comment: Just added, my apologies.

Comment: you should do startActivity(viewUser)

Comment: Ah - stupid mistake.  I tried changing it, but still not working.

Comment: Where do you receive your intent, in `onCreate` ?

Comment: Yup - correct @Eefret.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you never actually use the intent you create.

You called it `viewUser`, but when you call `startActivity` you pass `viewTheCameraImage` instead.

Comment: Yup - saw that and updated the code.  The intent is now passed, however, still getting the wrong information.